# When I use laravel5.8's redis queue function, it does not work properly

Tags: php, laravel, redis

The larave version is 5.8. I am going to use the queue function of redis. According to the documentation, when I start the queue: work command, it cannot be successfully executed. The error log has an abnormal error

**env:**

- laravel5.8
- php7.2.21
- redis5.0.5

**config/queue.php**

```
'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
            'queue' => env('REDIS_QUEUE', 'sso'),
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'block_for' => null,
        ],
```

**app/Jobs/LoginLog.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class LoginLog implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $data;
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($appId)
    {
        $this->data = $appId;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Log::info('job handle...',$this->data);
    }
}
```

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('test', function (){
    $appid = '1854956778';
    $a = \App\Jobs\LoginLog::dispatch($appid);
    dd($a);
});
```

**postman test**
[image: postman test]

**redis monitor**
[image: redis monitor]

**queue work**

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=sso
```

[image]

**error log**
[image: error log]

Comment: What happens when you just execute "php artisan queue:work" and also after restarting the queue

Comment: Nothing is output after the command is executed, and the error in the above picture is output in the error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the error is that the project introduced the php-enqueue / laravel-queue package. The 0.9 version of this package has a bug that was fixed after the upgrade